# Phonegap build facebook connect basic info permission

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have a "big" problem. My app using the facebook plugin, and when I authenticate the user, the dialog says: "The app must ask for a basic_info permission at install time."

What can I do with it? I googled long hours, but nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I used this 'old' stuff:

```
{scope : 'email'}
```

insted of this:

```
{perm : 'email'}
```